# How to discover a recursive relation in a data set?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, algorithms, machine-learning

For a set of data, $x(n)$, where $n = 1, 2, 3, ...$, we know there are some kind of recursive relations among those data, $x(n)$ somehow depends on previous data $x(n-1), x(n-2), ...x(1)$, but we do NOT know what kind of recursive relations they are.

For example, recursive relations can be:

$$x(n) = x(n - 1) + x(n-2) $$
or

$$x(n) = x(n-1)x(n-2) + x(n-3)$$
or any other type of recursive relations.

Question:
Is there an algorithm to discover hidden recursive relations in a data set?

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4505701/how-to-discover-a-recursive-relation-in-a-data-set) discusses recursive relations.

Comment: There is no general approach to finding a recurrence for a sequence. There are certain classes of problems that have general techniques, but the set of techniques is too large for a question here.

Comment: In particular, you say “data,” but data doesn’t define an infinite sequence, just a finite set of points.

Comment: You could do a linear regression (or polynomial regression) of $x(n)$ on $x(n-1), x(n-2), \ldots, x(n-k)$ for various $k$, and see if you get any that's an exact match on a held-out test set $x(n), n > N$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, Thank you. Can you give a reference to the general techniques you mentioned ? I should use the term "infinite sequence".

Comment: There are so many places where this comes up, it is hard to tell where to begin. I'd start with combinatorics books, where the sequence is defined in terms of counting finite sets depending on $n.$ We often fail to find "nice" closed formulas for such sequences, but can find recursions. But overall, there really isn't one book or subject to study. The reverse problem is more common - given a recursion, represent the sequence in another way - either as a closed form, or a generating function.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are fairly simple and fast methods for finding polynomials that match data exactly (As long as the data set size doesn't exceed 10^6, it'll work) (Newton-Gregory Interpolation, and much more, see 1. for a video on that topic), but assuming you want a simpler solution than the nth-degree polynomial that Newton-Gregory spits out, then a first guess is to throw it into OEIS - usually you'll find a sequence which is well defined, but not recursive - converting into a recursive relation shouldn't be too hard. 
If the internet doesn't give you any answers, then you could look into making a neural net that guesses an answer - no promises. The training data should be randomly generated recursively related sequences with simple rules. Then run it on the real deal - you should get a result pretty quickly. 
If that doesn't work - try doing a simple brute force search on a simpler version of the problem - restrict the recursions used, the operations used, and the past values used for the recursion, while allowing some mismatches in the data. (You won't find an exact solution using this way or the above.)
References:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AuV93LOPcE

Comment: thank you.  We know that the "hidden relation" in the set of data is NOT polynomial, and we could NOT find any matching OEIS. I like your suggestion of neural net, can you provide more details on how to using neural net for this problem ? What do you mean "The training data should be randomly generated recursively related sequences with simple rules. " ?

Comment: I meant that you could generate as much data is needed to train the network, since you're trying to find a recursive relation, you first need some recursive relations for the network to learn from - sequences with simple rules (formulas). Also look into RNNs (Recursive Neural Nets) and Transformers - pick which you need. Disclaimer, I'm not exactly an expert, but I love google scholar. [https://paperswithcode.com/paper/attention-is-all-you-need](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/attention-is-all-you-need)
A link to the transformers paper. Edit: oops wrong link

Comment: Thank you for your comments. " you first need some recursive relations for the network to learn from", how to do this ? How to generate enough recursive relations, for example, millions recursive relations for the network to learn ?

Comment: @david, to be honest, I don't really understand what you're saying here. Is there any problem with first generating a random set of numbers that are the initial conditions (for example, take the lucas sequence and the fibbonacci sequence, they have the same formula (rule), but they have different starting numbers, so you end up with a different recursive sequence.), and then adding random operations and valid recursive calls at the end of the current formula, then using the formula to generate a sequence, which would be labelled with the recursive rule used to generate it?

Comment: Thank you. In our situation, we have A PROCESS, which generate a set of numbers (infinite sequences),  we believe that there are "hidden" recursive relations among those numbers. But we do NOT know what they are, so we try to find it out. The PROCESS itself, we do NOT have any formula for it. It is just a PROCESS.